# [JPA-RELATIONSHIP-MAPPING]Using different annotations to map a pair of entities (for eg:@OneToOne and @OneToMany )

Tags: database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider a scenario where electives are being offered to students. Each student can only take one elective(which makes the student-elective @OneToOne) where as each elective can be opted by multiple-students(which will make the elective-student @ManyToOne). Is it fine to use @OneToOne <-> @ManyToOne to map my Student and Elective entities?

I got the result I was expecting, just wanted to make sure if this is the right practise.

Comment: Why would you use `@OneToOne` and/or `@ManyToMany` when the relationship is clearly Many-To-One/One-To-Many depending on the direction you are looking at it?

Comment: Sorry, That was wrong with how I framed my question. Is it safe to use  @OneToOne <-> @ManyToOne?

Comment: What do you mean by @OneToOne <-> @ManyToOne?